# How to reverse reformatting objects into an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let arr = [{key: 1, value: 10},
           {key: 5, value: 20}]
let reformatArr = arr.map(obj => {
     let tmp = {};
     tmp[obj.key] = obj.value
     return tmp;
});
//reformatArr is [{1: 10}, {5: 20}]
```

How can I reverse this process to its original format?I'm asking because I'm reformatting to send to my backend and want to reformat back when the data is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure the first element of `Object.entries` for each object.

```js
let reformatted = [{1: 10}, {5: 20}];
let res = reformatted.map(obj => {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(obj);
  return {key,value};
});
console.log(res);
```